# How to initialize a generic variable in Rust

Tags: generics, rust, initialization, polymorphism, parametric-polymorphism

In a function generic on `T`, how can I properly create and initialize a variable of type `T` in safe (or unsafe) Rust? `T` can be anything. What is the idiomatic way of doing such thing?

```rust
fn f<T>() {
    let t: T = todo!("what to put here?");
}
```

One possible use case might be to use `T` as a temporary variable for swapping.

Comment: If not `Default`, what would you want it to initialize to?

Comment: Both [`rotate_left`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.rotate_left) and [`rotate_right`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.rotate_right) methods on slices already exist in the standard library. And they use unsafe code to avoid having to put a `Default` trait bound on `T`.

Comment: @vallentin I don't know what I should initialize it to. I am new to Rust and that is my question, is there such a default.

Comment: @pretzelhammer yes I am aware of rotate_left and rotate_right. But that is not my question.

Comment: You already answered your own question. If you don't want to use unsafe code then you have to place a `Default` bound on `T` and initialize the generic type with `T::default()`. If you're willing to use unsafe code then you can look up the implementation for `rotate_right` within the Rust standard library, or just use `rotate_right` directly.

Comment: You're basically asking "How do I do X, other than the ways that the standard library and language permit me to do X?"

Comment: I voted to close because, having preemptively ruled out the answers you know of, you've left us with no real parameters for what kind of answer would be acceptable. `rotate_right` is in the standard library, and you can read the code for it -- it just uses `unsafe` (although admittedly not in exactly the way you refer to). What makes you think there needs to be *another* way? Or why do the two options you've ruled out not satisfy your requirements?

Comment: @trentcl rotate_left and rotate_right is not answer, because the question is not how to rotate. I am asking how to create an instance of a generic type. It turns out the Default solution which I already found is the best solution. But I had no idea that it was when I ask this question. There could be others in the same situation, so I think it should stay.

Comment: If you're not _sure_ whether you'll need a `T`, another option is `let mut t: Option<T> = None;`. It won't work in this example because you always need a `T`, but that's what idiomatic Rust code would use in preference to unsafe. The phrasing of your question is such that it's unclear whether this (or anything else, other than restating `T::default()`) contributes to the answer.

Comment: @user4815162342 maybe I should rephrase the question.

Comment: My point was not that you should use `rotate_right` necessarily, but that the question already contained two reasonable answers and seemed to be asking for "anything else?" without any real parameters on the solution. Since the edits the question no longer has this problem; I've revoked my close vote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting a `Default` bound on `T` is the idiomatic way to construct generic types within a generic function.

There's nothing special about the `Default` trait though and you can declare a similar trait and use that within your generic functions.

Also, if a type implements `Copy` or `Clone` you can initialize as many copies and clones as you want from a single value.

Commented examples:

```rust
// use Default bound to call default() on generic type
fn func_default<T: Default>() -> T {
    T::default()
}

// note: there's nothing special about the Default trait
// you can implement your own trait identical to it
// and use it in the same way in generic functions
trait CustomTrait {
    fn create() -> Self;
}

impl CustomTrait for String {
    fn create() -> Self {
        String::from("I'm a custom initialized String")
    }
}

// use CustomTrait bound to call create() on generic type
fn custom_trait<T: CustomTrait>() -> T {
    T::create()
}

// can multiply copyable types
fn copyable<T: Copy>(t: T) -> (T, T) {
    (t, t)
}

// can also multiply cloneable types
fn cloneable<T: Clone>(t: T) -> (T, T) {
    (t.clone(), t)
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b0a1d1a8e99f706f82a544196a20bda3)